# The intuition behind Trig substitutions in calculus

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I'm going through the MIT open calculus course, and in [one of the lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01-single-variable-calculus-fall-2006/video-lectures/lecture-28-inverse-substitution/) (19-28min marks) the professor uses the trig substitution $x = \tan \theta$ to find the integral of $\frac{dx}{x^2 \sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

His answer: $-\csc(\arctan  x) + c$, which he shows is equivalent to $-\frac{1+x^2}{x} + c$ by drawing a right triangle on the blackboard.

I get the math behind each step of it, but I can't wrap my head around why that equivalence works.  We just used an arbitrary $x = \tan \theta$ substitution, where $\theta$ moves differently than x does, and the expression $-\frac{1+x^2}{x} + c$ by itself doesn't know anything about trigonometry.  But I type both into Excel for a bunch of different x values, and obviously they are equivalent.

I guess I'm not really sure what my question is here, but I could just use some perspective.  It just seems like substituting ANY function in for x then integrating it shouldn't work, especially when crossing into polar coordinates.

Comment: It works because of the chain rule. When we change from $x$ to $\theta$, $dx$ changes to $\frac{dx}{d\theta}d\theta$. You can think of $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ accounting for the fact that $\theta$ and $x$ change differently.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that although $1/\sqrt{1+x^2}$ is difficult to integrate,
$$1/\sqrt{1+\tan^2 t}= 1/\sqrt{1/\cos^2 t}=\cos t$$
And together with $dx = dt/\cos^2 t $, leads to a very simple integral. In essence, any substitution "works", in the sense that all lead to the same numerical value, **but only some** of these lead to an easier integration.

As to the general idea behind substitution, take the easy example of $t = ax$:
$$\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_0^a \frac{f(x/a)}{a} dt $$
What's happening here? If you think geometrically, we just stretched the shape along the $x$-axis, so it's width is now $a$ instead of $1$. If we were to just naively substitute $t=ax$, the area would be $a$ times larger! and that is why we need to correct for this "stretching" by dividing by $dx/dt=a$.

As you mentioned, in the more general case the stretching is no longer uniform, but you can look at the new integral as a sum of differently stretched pieces, each with it's own correction factor $$dt/dx \neq \rm{const}$$.

By way of example, take a look at the integral over the half circle $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, with the transformation $x=\sin(t)$. You can see how the uniformly distributed widths in $x$ get "squeezed" differently in $t$:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I think my original question was confusingly written.  I see why the trig substitution leads to a simple integral, I just don't get why we can set x equal to any arbitrary function in any coordinate system.  The comment below my post says it's due to the chain rule, but $\theta$ doesn't move in the same way x does, and trig functions repeat while most other functions don't.  I wouldn't assume that derivatives in this case could be multiplied by one another like in the chain rule, but they can be somehow.  how?

Comment: @user1956609 - added some more explanations, hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate that.  Very helpful, thanks.

Comment: On the left picture $dt$ should be $dx$

Answer (score 2):

There are two key things to consider in this example:

A good way to try to integrate a function with a square root of a quadratic is to make a trig substitution, since the appropriate trig substitution will get rid of the square root.  In particular, when you have a square root of the form $\sqrt{x^2+a^2}$, substituting $x=a\tan\theta$ is a good thing to try since then the square root becomes $a\sec\theta$.

Whenever you have an expression of the form $f(g(x))$ where $f$ is a trig function and $g$ is an inverse trig function, then it can be simplified using a right triangle or using trig identities.

Answer (score 2):

The basic "family" of trigonometric substitutions uses the definitions of trig functions to produce a ratio $ \ \frac{x}{a} = \ $ [trig function] $\theta \ \rightarrow \ x = a \cdot $ [trig function] $\theta \ $ , $ \ a \ $ being a constant.  The legs and hypotenuse of a right triangle can produce three possibilities relating square roots of the sum or difference of two squared terms:

$ \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} \ $ can only be the hypotenuse of a right triangle with legs of lengths $ \ x \ $ and $ \ a \ $ .  It is the usual practice to make $ \ x \ $ the leg opposite the angle $ \ \theta \ $  and $ \ a \ $ the "adjacent" leg, which produces the ratio $ \ \tan \theta = \frac{x}{a} \ $ , as described above.  The associated differential is then $ \ dx = a \sec^2 \theta \ d\theta \ $ ; the radical is then given by $ \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}{a} = \sec \theta \ \rightarrow \ \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} = a \sec \theta \ $ .

The other arrangements involve differences of squared terms, which requires the radical to be the length of one of the triangle's legs.  We have either

$ \sqrt{x^2 - a^2} \ $ , which makes $ \ x \ $ the hypotenuse; generally, the side adjacent to $ \theta \ $ is chosen as the leg $ \ a \ $ , leading us to $ \ \sec \theta = \frac{x}{a} \ \rightarrow \ dx = a \sec \theta \tan \theta \ d\theta \ $ and $ \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}{a} = \tan \theta \ \rightarrow \ \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} = a \tan \theta \ $

or

$ \sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \ $ , making $ \ a \ $ the hypotenuse; the side *opposite* to $ \theta \ $ is usually chosen to be the leg $ \ x \ $ , giving $ \ \sin \theta = \frac{x}{a} \ \rightarrow \ dx = a \cos \theta \ d\theta \ $ and $ \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}{a} = \cos \theta \ \rightarrow \ \sqrt{x^2 + a^2} = a \cos \theta \ $ .

$$\\$$

Returning to your integral, the "tangent substitution" (with $ \ a \ = 1 \ $ ) produces

$$\int \ \frac{1 \cdot \sec^2 \theta \ d\theta}{1^2 \cdot \tan^2 \theta \ \cdot \ 1 \cdot \sec \theta} \  = \ \int \ \frac{\cos \theta \ d\theta}{ \sin^2 \theta } \ , $$

which can now be completed through a "$v-$subsitution" , $ \ v = \sin \theta \ $ , yielding the result

$$\int \ v^{-2} \ dv \ = \ -v^{-1} \ + \ C \ \rightarrow \ -\frac{1}{\sin \theta} \ + \ C \ \ \text{or} \ \ -\csc \theta \ + \ C \ . $$

[Maybe this was already clear to you, but you also seemed to be asking about the rationale for the choice of particular trig functions...]

Referring back to the associated right triangle, the side opposite $ \ \theta \ $ is $ \ x \ $ and the hypotenuse is $ \sqrt{x^2 + 1^2} \ $ , so the "back substitution" to return to a function of $ \ x \ $ gives us $ \ -\frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}{x} \ + \ C \ $ . (I believe you have omitted a radical in your expression; a check against WolframAlpha confirms this...)

Were we to simply construct a right triangle with the legs and hypotenuse described (and thus $ \ \theta = \arctan \frac{x}{1} \ $ ) and ask for the expression representing $ \ -\csc \theta \ $ , we would obtain this same result.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is based on the identity
$$
1+\tan ^{2}\theta =\sec ^{2}\theta .
$$
But there is another standard method to integrate  by substitution an *irrational* 
function of the type $f(R(x),\sqrt{a^2+x^{2}})$, where $R(x)$ is a rational function of $x$. This alternative method, which is based on the identity

$$1+\sinh ^{2}t=\cosh ^{2}t,$$

uses the hyperbolic substitution 
$$
x=\sinh t\Rightarrow dx=\cosh t\,dt,\qquad \text {or}\qquad x=a\sinh t,\quad \text {for a given } a.$$

As a matter of fact
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{dx}{x^{2}\sqrt{1+x^{2}}} &=&\int \frac{\cosh t}{\sinh ^{2}t\cosh t
}\,dt,\qquad x=\sinh t \\
&=&\int \frac{dt}{\sinh ^{2}t}=-\frac{\cosh t}{\sinh t}+C \\
&=&-\frac{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}{x}+C.
\end{eqnarray*}

The key issue is that both the trigonometric and the hyperbolic
substitutions lead to simpler integrals, because the irrational integrand becomes a rational function of trigonometric or hyperbolic functions.