# How do I evaluate $\int_{-R}^{R} \sqrt{R^2-x^2}\,dx$ using the change of variables $x = R\sin(w)$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

I'm trying to answer this question from my calculus 1 exam I did last December.

The question asks us to compute a definite integral by using the following change of variables $$ x=R \sin(w)$$ in the following equation:
$$\int_{-R}^R \sqrt{R^2-x^2} \  dx $$
The thing that's confusing me is how to do this change of variable if the equation is already expressed in terms of $x$?

Comment: If $x = R\sin(w)$, then $w = $...?

Comment: There are a *lot* of related questions on Math StackExchange.  For example: [\[1\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153468), [\[2\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476890), [\[3\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638051), [\[4\]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966113).

Comment: As opposed to the other way of computing it, which is to note it's the area of a semicircle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define $x$ in terms of $w$ via the given rule. To make the change of variable you notice that
$$\frac{dx}{dw}=R\cos(w)\iff dx=R\cos(w)\,dw$$
thus the integral becomes
\begin{align*}
\int_{-R}^R\sqrt{R^2-x^2}\,dx&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{R^2-R^2\sin^2(w)}\cdot R\cos(w)\,dw\\
&=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}R\cos(w)\cdot R\cos(w)\,dw\\
&=R^2\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos^2(w)\,dw
\end{align*}
you can end it from here.